# Regex: match patterns

Tags: regex

So I have a string of numbers. There are certain rules I need.
It can have tel1 or tel2 at start (or not)
If E is in number it must be foolowed by 4 digits then followed by 49. (Optional pattern)

So a string like:

```
tel1: +E1234498912345678,tel2: +498912345678,tel1: +E123449D1238912345678,tel2: +E1234498912345678
```

is valid

```
tel1: +E12344598912345678,tel2: +498912345678,tel1: +E123449D1238912345678,tel2: +E1234498912345678
```

is invalid (first element invalid)

And also each element must begin with + like in examples

UPDATE: Also needs to match numbers with '@' suffix

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
^((\s*tel[12]:\s*)?\+(E\d{4}49|\d)[^,]*(,|$))+$
```

Try the demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/eO5yO1/2).

Comment: Using that, this is valid: tel1: +E1234498912345678,tel2: +498912345678,tel1: +E123449D1238912345678,tel2: +E12345498912345678. Last element should cause it to fail

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://regex101.com/r/oG6lH3/1

```
(tel\d: |)\+(E\d\d\d\d49|49)
```

This will also match tel3 or tel9. If that is an issue, use one of the other provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((tel1|tel2)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49\w+(,|$)|(tel1|tel2)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)\w+(,|$))+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/3

Comment: That looks good thanks. I'd like to change options for tel1/tel2 to be: sip/tel. So I'm using ^((sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49\w+(,|$)|(sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)\w+(,|$))+$ on this valid string: sip: +E1234498912345678@destinazione1.italtel.it,tel: +498912345678,sip: +E123449D1238912345678@destinazione1.italtel.it,sip: +E1234498912345678@origine1.italtel.it but no match. Am I missing something?

Comment: @En-Motion it has `@` which is not covered by `\w`

Comment: @En-Motion `^((sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.]+(,|$)|(sip|tel)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)[@\w.]+(,|$))+$ ` try this

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
^\s*(?:(?:tel[12]):\s*\+(?:E(?=\d{4}49)\S+?\b|\d+))(?:,(?:(?:tel[12]):\s*\+(?:E(?=\d{4}49)\S+?\b|\d+)))+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH7pG6/8)